# ember.js displaying list of items, each item with it's own view/controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js

What I want to achieve: 
create controller with view, and in this view I have list of 'Gallery' objects. Each item has it's own view and controller.

All files are here: https://gist.github.com/7e72bb2f532c171b1bf3

It works as intended, after hovering some text is shown/hidden, but personally I think that this it's not so good solution.

I think that I maybe should use {{collection}} helper, but there is no documentation for it on ember.js page (there is some in code, but I'm not sure if this helper is not a little bit outdated, as in source it says "// TODO: Don't require all of this module").

I tried to use itemController property, but then I still have template in one file.

Also tried to use {{render}} helper in {{#each}}, but then it throw error.

So, It is there a better/cleaner way to achieve what I want?

**EDIT**

After making everything as in explanation provided by Michael Grassotti, I have strange behaviour - property to template is taken fron itemController, but {{action}} helper binds to parent controller. I have made screenshot to show what I'm dealing with.

[image]

Basically "this" in itemView points to right controller (itemController) but target property has parent controller.

After making `{{action "deleteGallery" this target="this"}}` and clicking it, I have error as in screenshot. At this moment, I'm running out of ideas...

**EDIT2:**

ok, I'm overthinking it, itemController is only for defining computed properties, not for writing {{action}} handlers.

**EDIT3:**
I think that my problem with itemController and event target will be fixed. 
https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1846

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I think that I maybe should use {{collection}} helper, but there is no documentation for it on ember.js page (there is some in code, but I'm not sure if this helper is not a little bit outdated, as in source it says "// TODO: Don't require all of this module").

Agreed. Collection helper still works but I'm not certain it will be part of the public-api going forward. Best to stick with the `{{#each}}` helper if you can.

> I tried to use itemController property, but then I still have template in one file.

The `itemController` property is a good start. that's the best way to give each item it's own controller.

> Also tried to use {{render}} helper in {{#each}}, but then it throw error.

Yeah the `{{render}}` helper is not designed for use within an `{{each}}` block.

> So, It is there a better/cleaner way to achieve what I want?

Yep. For starters use the `itemController` property. Then to give each it's own view, provide an `itemViewClass` option to the `{{each helper}}`. For example:

```
# in galleries_index.hbs
{{each controller itemViewClass="App.GalleriesIndexItemView"}
```

See the "blockless use" section of [api docs for the each helper](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_each) for detail.

Then customize `App.GalleriesIndexItemView` to specify a template:

```
App.GalleriesIndexItemView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: "galleries_index_item",
    tagName: 'li',
    classNames: ['span4'],
    hover: false,
    mouseEnter: function() {
        this.set('hover', true);
    },
    mouseLeave: function() {
        this.set('hover', false);
    }
});
```

and move html from the each helper to into the template:

```
# galleries_index_item.hbs
  <div class="thumbnail">
      <a href="#">
          <img src="images/300x200.gif" alt="">
      </a>
      <div class="caption">
          <h4>{{name}}</h4>              
          {{#if view.hover}}
              <button {{action editGallery this }} class="btn btn-mini" type="button">Edit</button>
              <button {{action deleteGallery this}} class="btn btn-mini" type="button">Delete</button>
          {{/if}}
      </div>
  </div>
```

Now every item has it's own view and controller.

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I wanted, but currently I'm again banging my head against a wall. Look at: https://gist.github.com/c4e6adb87846737f8e6c - template uses property from controller "omgTest" but it uses the deleteGallery from parent controller?

Comment: Hmmm - saw your edit above. FWIW I agree seems the action helper should be targeting your `itemController`. I'll have a look and see what I can find out.

Comment: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1846 - I think this will be fixed in next version of ember.

Comment: Thanks Kamil - hadn't seen that issue but agreed looks like a fix is on the way.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to use an [`Ember.CollectionView`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.CollectionView.html).

Your `galleriesIndex` template will looks like:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            {{view App.GalleriesListView contentBinding="this"}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The view:

```
App.GalleriesListView = Ember.CollectionView.extend({
    classNameBindings: [':thumbnail', ':thumbnails-list'],
    itemViewClass: Ember.View.extend({
        templateName: "galleriesListItem",
        hover: false,
        mouseEnter: function() { this.set('hover', true); },
        mouseLeave: function() { this.set('hover', false; }
    })
});
```

The `galleriesListItem` template:

```
<li class="span4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="images/300x200.gif" alt="">
        </a>
        <div class="caption">
            <h4>{{view.content.name}}</h4>                        
            {{#if view.hover}}
                <button {{action editGallery view.content }} class="btn btn-mini" type="button">Edit</button>
                <button {{action deleteGallery view.content}} class="btn btn-mini" type="button">Delete</button>
            {{/if}}
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

I am not sure there is no error in my code, I just copy-paste and write how it should looks like.

Concerning the `TODO` you saw, this is because the `Ember.CollectionView` actually needs all the `ember-handlebars` module instead of just the file it needs, you should not care about that.

Comment: thank You for answer, but Michael Grassotti provided better answer :) (showed how to connect controller for each item)

Comment: I thought you know that because you said you did try to use itemController. Anyway, +1 for @Michael Grassotti, I like its answer better than mine!