# How to implement Graph Edition View in EmberJS

Tags: user-interface, ember.js, implementation

I'm a rails developer and new to EmberJS and I ask for a little help implementing the UI, because it's heavy in javascript code and I want to try Ember

Here's what I want to accomplish

[image]

When I click the GraphEditor it adds a new Actor and shows the new actor popover form

The thing is that the UI elements are made with SVG tags in order to be zoomable, pannable and  things like that

My problems are

- Which controllers keep track of Actors and Relations? How to invoke them from the SocialNetwork show view?
- How to render the Actors and Relations views? {{render}} doesn't work multiple times, and I need to bound the view properties with the model properties (kind of render partial: 'actor', actor: actor)
- How I can create the Actor/Relation Details Popover view?
- How do you structure the view hierarchy in order to accomplish this? My proposition is to have this nested views hierarchy.

[image]

Sorry about the general question but I'm implementing this in Ember because It's a complex view bound to data and I don't know how to implement this. Any initial insight would be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which controllers keep track of Actors and Relations?

Probably your `ActorsController` will be an array controller with list of actors, and that list will be populated in `SocialNetwork` route's `setupController` hook. Could do the same for relations or maybe they are accessible via the actors, depending on how your model data is structured.

> How to invoke them from the SocialNetwork show view?

Add `needs: ['actors'] to`SocialNetworkController`so that the property`controllers.actors` will be available.

> How to render the Actors and Relations views?

Use `{{each}}` helper to loop over list of actors/relations, and specify itemController property so that each actor is wrapped in an instance of `ActorController`

```
{{#each actor in controllers.actors itemController="actor"}}
  {{actor.name}} {{#if actor.isAwesome}}***AWESOME****{{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

> How I can create the Actor/Relation Details Popover view?

Pretend it's not a popover, get it working so that details show up in some div as if you were doing a normal master/detail view. Then once it's working customize the detail view's didInsertElement fx so that it shows up in a popup instead.

> How do you structure the view hierarchy in order to accomplish this?

There are many ways to do this, here's an (untested) sketch. I am assuming that GraphEditorView is going to take care of the SVG stuff - otherwise that view is not really needed.

```
<!-- social_network.hbs -->
<h3>Network Name: {{name}}</h3>
{{view "App.GraphEditorView"}}

<!-- graph_editor.hbs -->
<h3>Network Name: {{name}}</h3>
{{#each actor in controllers.actors itemController="actor"}}
  <g class="actor" {{action showDetails}}>
    <circle></circle>
    <text>{{actor.name}}</text>
  </g>
  {{#if actor.isShowingDetails}}
    {{render actorDetails actor}}
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

> Sorry about the general question but I'm implementing this in Ember because It's a complex view bound to data and I don't know how to implement this. Any initial insight would be useful

No worries. Maybe see this related post maybe it might help to see how these concepts apply to somebody else's app: [ember.js displaying list of items, each item with it's own view/controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14612663/ember-js-displaying-list-of-items-each-item-with-its-own-view-controller)

Comment: I've updated the content of the question showing a view hierarchy proposal of the whole rendered page

Comment: Proposal makes sense. Seems like you've got a handle on it so not clear on what you are asking re: 'structure the view hierarchy', updating my answer with best guess...